# vuejs test component with properties inside parent element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm test a custom component with vue test utils and Jest. My component uses Vuetify component, and so I need to declare a div with `data-app` attribute, in order to have the menu rendered (if I dont, I get the following error :

```
wrapper = mount(MyComponent,  {
  propsData: {
    value: 1
}});
```

> [Vuetify] Unable to locate target [data-app]

If my component didn't use any properties, I would do like this:

```
wrapper = mount(Vue.extend({
    template: `<div data-app="true"><MyComponent /></div>`,
}), {
    attachToDocument: true
});
```

But, then, I can't set component properties, can I?

So I thought about using `parentComponent` property like this:

```
const parent = {
    template: `<div data-app="true"><MyComponent /></div>`,
};

wrapper = mount(MyComponent,  {
    parentComponent: parent,
    propsData: {
        value: 1'
    }});
```

But it does not work either.

Is there any way to test my component?

Comment: What properties do you want to pass to your `MyComponent`?

Comment: Any prop... In my example there is one prop named "value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was not to use `parentComponent`, but define an ad hoc component for testing. For example if my component has 2 props `prop1` and `prop2`

```
wrapper = mount(Vue.extend({
    template: `<div data-app="true"><MyComponent :prop1=prop1 :prop2=prod2 /></div>`,
}), {
    attachToDocument: true,
    props: ['prop1', 'prop2'],
    propsData: ['value1', 'value2']
});
```